# MathLink and a function of a real variable

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp

I am trying to use a real function of a real variable written in C from Mathematica, my .tm file reads as follows:

```
:Begin:
:Function:       my_function
:Pattern:        MyFunction[ x_Real]
:Arguments:      { x }
:ArgumentTypes:  { Real }
:ReturnType:     Real
:End:

double my_function(double x) { /* snip */ return ret; }
```

I can compile with mcc, install the program from within Mathematica, and call my function as MyFunction[1.0], but it won't work if I call it with an integer argument, like MyFunction[1], as it is not automatically converted to a Real and then to a double.

How can I make my function work well also with integer arguments?

Also I have to apply some numerical Mathematica methods (like NMinimize, NIntegrate) and they fail when evaluating the function for integer values.

Comment: You can "overload" your function like `MyFunction[x_Integer]:=MyFunction[N[x]]`.

Comment: That's what I need, I thought that N[integer] would remain an integer, but this is not the case. If you want to convert your comment into an answer I will accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When your C-function takes a `double` argument, then your template definition is not optimal, because the pattern `x_Real` forbids you to put anything else than a *real number*.

It's far more general if your function can take all arguments which *can be converted into a real number*. Two steps are required for this. First, you change your pattern to

```
:Pattern:        MyFunction[ x_?NumericQ]
```

which lets you even call your function with `Pi` or `1` or `1/E`. Second thing, and this is probably not widely known: the `:Arguments:` section can evaluate code! Therefore, you can make the transition to a real number there:

```
:Arguments:      { N[x] }
```

Now you can call your *MathLink* function without a wrapper, because things like `1`, `Pi` and `2/3` are converted automatically.

Comment: +1, for the info on the `:Arguments:` section, alone. (The rest could be deserving of an upvote, also, but you'll have to work harder. :))